# Deleting my old Wordpress site. - issues

Tags: customization

Im trying to delete my Wordpress site.

I am the admin but every time I go to the dashboard, under settings there is no option to delete site just export and import.

I want this site gone.

Comment: A WordPress website is nothing more than files and a database, delete those and delete your site.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default option for delete a WordPress site from WordPress admin. If you want the website gone, you can just delete the database from cPanel/phpMyAdmin and delete all files.

Of course, if you used a software install like Softaculous, there you will find an option to uninstall the website.